# Zend Framework: Submit and redirect

Tags: zend-framework

That is my form:

```
class Application_Form_Search extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {
    $searchFor = new Zend_Form_Element_Text(array('name' => 'searchFor', 'class' => 'input-text search-box', 'value' => 'Search'));
    $searchFor->setAttribs(array('onclick' => 'this.value="";', 'onfocus' => 'this.select()', 'onblur' => 'this.value=!this.value?"Search":this.value;'))
            ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',));

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit(array('name' => 'search', 'class' => 'input-submit-search search-box', 'label' => ''));
    $submit->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',));

    $this->addElements(array($searchFor, $submit));
}
```

}

That is my search action:

```
 public function searchresultAction() {
    $form = new Application_Form_Search();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($form->isValid($postdata)) {
            $this->_redirect('Search/Results);
        }
    }.......
```

Problem is that, when I click submit button I don't redirect to Search/Results, in postdata don't have values. I call my form in layout.phtml.

Comment: Is the form posting to the correct controller and action?  What is the output HTML for the form?

Comment: I call form in layouts/scripts/layout.phtml maybe for that I don't see anything with var_dump

Comment: I just see nowhere that you set your form action to somecontroller/searchresult so I don't know that it's even posting to the right action.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in the code you posted.  The redirect line should be `$this->_redirect('Search/Results');`

Assuming this is just a typo in your question but not in your code, IIRC using `$this->_redirect()` sends an [HTTP 302 Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) response with a [Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) which causes the browser to load a new page using a GET request.  So if the POST data isn't included in the Location header's URL, it will be lost.

You can use `$this->_forward()` to avoid the 302 redirect and just have ZF load a different module/controller/action.  You can also use this method to pass arguments.

Otherwise, why forward or do a redirect at all?  Why not just continue processing the data and show the results using your `searchresultAction` itself?